# Python project not able to find file

Tags: ubuntu, python

I'm working with a [python file](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/neural_style_transfer.py) that requires two pictures as an input and returns another picture which is the result of the first two. Using the terminal you are supposed to input the file path to these two pictures and the prefix for the results in this format:

```
python neural_style_transfer.py path_to_your_base_image.jpg \
    path_to_your_reference.jpg prefix_for_results
```

When I enter:

```
python neural_style_transfer.py /home/ryan/Desktop/Cat.jpg \ /home/ryan/Desktop/Art.jpg /home/ryan/Desktop
```

I get the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ' /home/ryan/Desktop/Art.jpg'
```

Notice that there's a space between the first quote and the first /. I am unsure why this is.

Also worth noting, entering `locate Art.jpg` and `locate Cat.jpg` returns `/home/ryan/Desktop/Art.jpg` and `/home/ryan/Desktop/Cat.jpg`, respectively.

The two jpg files are still on my desktop and don't have any additional whitespace in their names.

Comment: Is the leading space a symptom or a typo in the question?

Comment: The locate command doesn't mean that the data exists. It could have been deleted and the database hasn't been updated. Run updatedb and then see if locate returns it. Also, run `ls -lQ` on `/home/ryan/Desktop` which will list the data inside surrounded by quotation marks. It's possible that the filename has trailing whitespace.

Comment: In your first example, the backslash (``\``) is used ***at the end of a line*** to let you span a command over multiple lines.  The backslash and the newline *(which must follow it **immediately**)* combine to form nothing.  But then you used a backslash in the middle of a line.  That’s your problem.  Even then, if you had said `…Cat.jpg \/home/ryan/Desktop/Art.jpg`, you would have been OK.  But, by saying `…Cat.jpg \ /home/ryan/Desktop/Art.jpg`, you had a backslash immediately followed by a space, and they combine to form a literal space — a space that is part of an argument, … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … rather than a separator between arguments.  So your `Art.jpg` argument becomes `(space)` `/` `h` `o` `m` `e` `/` `r` `y` `a` `n` `/` `D` `e` `s` `k` `t` `o` `p` `/` `A` `r` `t` `.` `j` `p` `g` (where the first character is a literal space).  This is a valid pathname, although obviously not what you wanted to say.  There’s no such file, so you got the error message that says that there’s no such file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
No such file or directory: ' /home/ryan/Desktop/Art.jpg'
```

Note the leading whitespace in the quoted pathname in the error message. If that's actually included in the variable that contains the pathname, and not just an extra space in the python command that outputs the error message, the error happens because the pathname the program is looking for is actually **not**:

```
/home/ryan/Desktop/Art.jpg
```

but

```
./ /home/ryan/Desktop/Art.jpg
```

relative to whatever is the current working directory of the Python program.

When you type in a multi-line command line like

```
python neural_style_transfer.py path_to_your_base_image.jpg \
    path_to_your_reference.jpg prefix_for_results
```

as a single line, you should delete the backslash too:

```
python neural_style_transfer.py /home/ryan/Desktop/Cat.jpg /home/ryan/Desktop/Art.jpg /home/ryan/Desktop
```

If you leave the backslash in and place a space (instead of a line-feed character) after it, it's the same as typing:

```
python neural_style_transfer.py /home/ryan/Desktop/Cat.jpg  ' /home/ryan/Desktop/Art.jpg' /home/ryan/Desktop
```

Which, in turn, is the same as:

```
python neural_style_transfer.py /home/ryan/Desktop/Cat.jpg './ /home/ryan/Desktop/Art.jpg' /home/ryan/Desktop
```

Which is obviously not what you intended, but that's how your Python program understood it.

Comment: If I do this for all path names `python neural_style_transfer.py ./ /home/ryan/Desktop/Art.jpg \ ./ /home/ryan/Desktop/Art.jpg ./ /home/ryan/Desktop/Art.jpg` I get `neural_style_transfer.py: error: unrecognized arguments: /home/ryan/Desktop/Art.jpg ./ /home/ryan/Desktop/Art.jpg`.

Comment: You’re not supposed to add `./ ` in front of every path, telcoM is using that to explain what is happening. Forget `./ `, forget backslashes, enter the file names as they are without adding anything to them.

Comment: Edited to clarify based on the information added to the question. Does this make it any clearer?

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining it clearly.